# Roots of a polynomial satisfying $f(x^{2}+1) = f(x) \cdot g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f(x), g(x)$ be $2$ real polynomials of degrees ($m\ge 2$) and $(n\ge 1 )$ respectively satisfying $$f(x^{2}+1) = f(x) \cdot g(x)$$

for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then which of the below options are true:

- $f$ has exactly one real root $x_{0}$ such that $f'(x_{0}) \ne 0$
- $f$ has exactly one real root $x_{0}$ such that $f'(x_{0}) = 0$
- $f$ has $m$ distinct real roots.
- $f$ has no real roots.

Since $\operatorname{deg}(f(x)) = m$ therefore $\operatorname{deg}(f(x^{2})) =2m$ and so by comparing degree on both sides we get that $2m=m+n \implies m=n$. But this doesn't lead me anywhere. I think perhaps one should look into Rolle's theorem, but I am not sure as to how to apply them.

Answer (score 1):

What you can prove is that $f$ has no real root (only the 4th claim is true).

For, assume that $x$ is a root of $f$. By the equation, you obtain that $x^2+1$ is also a root of $f$. The key point is that $x^2+1=x$ has no real solution, so $x^2+1$ is another real root of $f$ (*). It follows that, starting from a root $x_0$, the sequence $x_{n+1}=x_n^2+1$ is an infinite (since monotonic) sequence of roots of $f$. Which is impossible since $f$ is not $0$ (it has degree $m\geq2$). So $f$ has no real root.

(*) For example, the equation $f(x^2)=f(x)g(x)$ would have a completely different solution.